# How to Make Web Service Call Without Making the GUI Unresponsive

Tags: iphone

I have a `UISearchBar` and `UISearchDisplayController`. When the user writes text in it inside  `searchBar:textDidChange:` I make a web-service call to filter my TableView. The problem is that the GUI get unresponsive until I get the result from the web-service. I've tried to solve it using `[self performSelector:@selector(callWebService:) withObject:searchText];`, but it's still unresponsive.

EDIT: Following Flink advice, I changed `performSelector` to `performSelectorInBackground`, but now the tableView doesn't filter correctly, it only show 'No Results'.
even `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` isn't get called.

EDIT Again: The reason I got 'No Results' was due to not calling `reloadData` on the correct tableView. `UISearchDisplayController` has a property named `searchResultsTableView`. So in the end what I used was `[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:false];` and now it works fine.

It should be noted that although I chose the `performSelectorInBackground`, I probably should have tried to use `sendAsynchronousRequest` method on `NSURLConnection` - See AliSoftware's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your web call async.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial

In your case, you can change `performSelector` to `performSelectorInBackground`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've changed it now to `performSelectorInBackground `, but now the tableview shows 'No Results'

Comment: I even added at the end of the webservice call function `[tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:false];` but it's still not showing any results.

Comment: It'll be easier to give better answer if you provide the code here

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid creating a background queue or thread to perform your network request(which is what `performSelectorInBackground:` does) as this creates a worker thread just for this which is not as efficient as scheduling the request on the `NSRunLoop`.

Dedication a thread will make the processor activate the thread regularly to check if there are some data, and creating a thread for that is quite overkill. Scheduling the request on the run loop (as a run loop source) will use network interruptions to signal incoming data from the socket and thus will only be activated when there is actual data available.

To do this, simply **use the asynchronous methods provided by `NSURLConnection`**.

- One solution is to use the delegate approach provided by `NSURLConnection` (this is the old way to do it, the only way that was available in the `NSURLConnection` API back in iOs3)
- Another more modern solution is to use the block API provided by `NSURLConnection` which is easier to use and code.

  ```
  [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                     queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                         completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse* response, NSData* receivedData, NSError* error)
   {
     // Your code to execute when the network request has completed
     // and returned a response (or timed out or encountered an error)
     // This code will execute asynchronously only once the whole data is available
     // (the rest of the code in the main thread won't be blocked waiting for it)
   }];
  // After this line of code, the request is executed in the background (scheduled on the run loop)
  // and the rest of the code will continue: the main thread will not be frozen during the request.
  ```

Read more in the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) and in the [`NSURLConnection` class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the kind of thing the block is used for!